# People Tracking Library

Tags: image-processing, compilation

Can anyone direct me to a free people tracking library? I would like to be able to use an input image (or video) and get the position of people in it. I have looked at the [Reading People Tracker](http://www.siebel-research.de/people_tracking/reading_people_tracker/) but cannot compile it! I am on Linux (Ubuntu) but windows would be okay (if anyone can tell me how, this would be great). Preferably, it would be for C/C++ but java, c#, ruby and python would be okay too. Thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good if you'd let us know why you can't compile ´Reading People Tracker´? Maybe you could link here to your StackOverflow question with your compile error.

Comment: That would be a very good idea, apologies. I can't access my computer at present but if I remember correctly, even though I install the dependencies, the makefile can't find them. I think the makefile looks for the libraries in the root folder or it expects some kind of symbolic link I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically a people tracking library, but as a general tracking approach "Predator" is very highly regarded: http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html - Authors site includes some very impressive demonstration of results on youtube

Answer (score 0):

[This article fully explains](http://joelbecker.net/blog/video-motion-tracking-2) an algorithm used for tracking moving people, and [the accompanying source code is here](https://github.com/voxoid0/java-motion-tracking); it is pure Java. You can [see it in action in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aFDTZlR7DM).

(Disclaimer: I'm the author; but I do think this is very useful, and have successfully used the algorithm a lot myself.)

The algorithm tracks moving objects in general, finds their bounding rectangle (which the application draws), counts the number of pixels in each objects, and consistently assigns them the same integer ID throughout the video frames.

When it comes to commercial computer vision applications, [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) and the [Point Cloud Library aka PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) are your best friends (C++, but there are Java and C# bindings). And articles like the one linked explains how to use tools like OpenCV to accomplish full stack motion tracking. (The pure Java implementation shows how it works down to the individual pixels.)